# redux store change not immediately visible to component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Im trying to create a formbuilder using drag and drop functions. Im maintaining the state using Redux. I have two items in initial state(allItems array and dragItem). My reducer looks like the following:

```
import { ActionTypes } from '../constants/ActionTypes.js'
const intialState = {
    allItems: [],
    dragItem: ""
}
export const builderReducer = (state = { intialState }, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ActionTypes.addItem:
            return {
                ...state,
                allItems: action.payload
            }
        case ActionTypes.dragItem:
            return {
                ...state,
                dragItem: action.payload
            }
        default:
            return state
    }

}
```

drag Item is updated on dragstart event everytime the user drags a component . all items is updated evrytime the user drops the component in workspace. once i drop the component store gets updated correctly . However im not immediately able to collect the changed store value . it is taking two drag and drops to get the store value . it says undefined at the first place i try to use it . on second drag and drop i get both the values together . Below image will explain what i am trying to do .
[image]

Comment: try putting the console log in a useEffect with data as dependency?

Comment: it throws an error : useEffect received a final argument that is not an array (instead, received `object`). When specified, the final argument must be an array.

Comment: ```useEffect(() => console.log(....), [data])``` note the []

Comment: I suspect you may need to add a `useCallback()` to your `dropHandler()`

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

This is the result of a [Javascript Closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) over the selected `data` state from the store in the current "instance" of the `dropHandler` callback.

1. `Workspace` renders

   1. `data` is declared with the selected `state.allItems` value
   2. `dropHandler` is declared and closes over the `data` value in callback scope
2. `dropHandler` is called

   1. Incorrectly uses `.map` function to iterate the `items` array
   2. Dispatches `addItems` and `dragItem` to the store
   3. Logs the ***closed over*** "stale" `data` value
   4. Incorrectly uses `.map` again to mutate `myContent` using the stale `allItems` array

## Solutions

Use a `useEffect` hook with a dependency on the `data` state value.

Example:

```js
const { allItems, dragItem } = useSelector(state => state.allItems);

...

React.useEffect(() => {
  console.log({ allItems });

  if (allItems) {
    allItems.forEach(res => {
      if (res === "inputBox") {
        myContent.push(<input type="text" />);
      }
      if (res === "selectBox") {
        myContent.push(
          <select name="options">
            <option value="1">one</option>
            <option value="2">two</option>
            <option value="3">three</option>
          </select>
        );
      }
    });
  }
}, [allItems]);

const dropHandler = () => {
  items.forEach(res => {
    if (res.name === dragItem) {
      formItems.push(res.name);
      dispatch(addItem(formItems));
      dispatch(dragItem(""));
    }

  });
};

...
```

An alternative, less recommended, method would be to import the store and access the store's ***current*** state within the `handleDrop` callback *after* the dispatched actions.

Example:

```js
...
import store from '../path/to/store';

...

const data = useSelector(state => state.allItems);

...

const dropHandler = () => {
  items.forEach(res => {
    if (res.name === data.dragItem) {
      formItems.push(res.name);
      dispatch(addItem(formItems));
      dispatch(dragItem(""));
    }

  });

  const { allItems } = store.getState().allItems;

  console.log({ allItems });

  if (allItems) {
    allItems.forEach(res => {
      if (res === "inputBox") {
        myContent.push(<input type="text" />);
      }
      if (res === "selectBox") {
        myContent.push(
          <select name="options">
            <option value="1">one</option>
            <option value="2">two</option>
            <option value="3">three</option>
          </select>
        );
      }
    });
  }
};

...
```